# how to Send data to the client app after publishing the app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, publish

I have made a music app and I want to update the contents(song)  without updating the whole app and client should receive the push notification about the updates I know It can be done with Google cloud messaging service but how exactly it will be done do I have to own a hosting server
And last question how can i updates the songs in the client app when GCM
Allowed small amount of data to be transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have a server that collects the registration IDs of the devices that installed your application, and sends GCM messages to them.

If all you wanted was to send GCM messages to your app, you could use some 3rd party push notifications service (such as UrbanAirship), and perhaps you wouldn't need your own server.

However, since you can't use GCM to upload a new song to the app (since a GCM message is limited to 4096 bytes), your GCM message would just notify your app of the need to download a new song (the message could contain, for example the song name, or the URL to download the song from), and your app will download that song from your server. That's why you need a server.

Comment: Can I use php base server and it will be hosted from my own PC

Comment: @user3700517 You're welcome! You can use a php base server (or any other programming language), but hosting it from your own PC means your app will be able to access the server only if your device is connected to the internet via the same local network as your PC (i.e. it will only work with WiFi connection).